# ASP .NET MVC 4 Application as Multi Tenant application on windows azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, multi-tenant

I have a mvc 4 application. I already have one field (CompanyID) in database tables. Now we are planning to put this application on windows azure as a multi tenant application. I have studied many forums and much more. No one gives perfect description regarding how to make my existing mvc 4 application as a multi tenant compatible with windows azure.

Can we achieve this with existing application and windows azure?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Can we achieve this with existing application and windows azure?

Surely you can. I can hardly find any scenario that works elsewhere, especially on Microsoft's stack of technologies, that cannot be moved to Azure.

> I have studied many forums and much more. No one gives perfect
>   description regarding how to make my existing mvc 4 application as a
>   multi tenant compatible with windows azure.

There is no single one `this is how you do it`. There are multiple ways of achieving same goal. That's why you cannot find the answer to your own concrete solution.

Let me ask you a question:

- Have you created your MVC4 application to work as multi-tenant application for your local IIS server?

If the answer is `NO` - then first do it locally, make sure it works locally, and then ask questions how to move to Azure.

If the answer is `YES` - then what is the specific issue you face during moving your app to Azure.

Comment: Thank you astaykov. By looking into your answer i would like to know some basics from you. As you said "Have you created your MVC4 application to work as multi-tenant application for your local IIS server?". I have mentioned about CompanyID in DB tables. I just have implemented our application to differentiate different company user by their company id. Can u pls help me how can i achieve this so my application will act as a multi tenant.  Thanks again.